# How to find the trending phrases or most frequent phrases from text data in Python?

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining, n-gram, pos-tagger

I have text data in the form of pandas data frame object. Each row of the text column contains single or multiple sentences. I would like to find the most frequent or trending phrases from the text.

Comment: Can you show how the input and output look like?

Comment: What constitutes trending? Like a sudden rise in frequency that continues to rise at the end of the curve, or a spike in frequency at some point in the past, or something else?